# regex to allow string, string followed by numbers, and hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I wanna regex which will allow the following samples

```
1) abcd
2) abcd123
3) abcd-123
```

which should not allow

```
1) 123abcd
2) 123
3) 123-123
```

Comment: You can use: `/^[a-z]+-?\d*$/i`

Comment: Great. Its working as expected. I just want to understand this. Can you please explain this?

Comment: Added explanation in answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[a-z]+-?\d*$/i
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^` - Assert start
- `[a-z]+` - Match 1 or more alphabets
- `-?` - Match an optional hyphen
- `\d*` - Match 0 or more digits
- `$` - Assert end

Comment: Thanks for the explantation. @anubhava

Answer (score 0):

I think, if lowercase

```
[a-z]-?\d
```